# How to make @Schedule method to be called only once at a time

Tags: annotations, timeout, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1, schedule

We are using the `@Schedule` EJB annotation to start a scheduled job do a delta SOLR import every x seconds. Of course we want to have as less timeshift in indexing as possible. Currently I try to do the delta every 5 seconds.

So my question is: Can I make sure the job is only called once?
So let's say the indexing is lasting longer than 5 seconds, will the next schedules call wait until the previous is coming back?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can make the bean a `@Singleton` and use [`@Lock(LockType.Write)`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Lock.html) to make sure that timers don't run in parallel. Note that `LockType.Write` is the default in a Singleton. So even the explicit mention with the annotation would not be required.