# Make a method inside EJB @Schedule to be called only once

Tags: java, annotations, ejb, schedule

So I have a relatively simple EJB. I want to check every ten seconds for a pdf file at a specific location and when I find it send a mail. Work fine and as expected but I always receive two identical email instead of one.The code is like this:

```
@Stateless
public class TimerBean {

    private EmailService emailService ;
    private boolean fileNotFound;

    public TimerBean(){
       this.fileNotFound= true;
       emailService = new EmailService();
    }

    @Schedule(second = "*/10", minute = "*", hour = "*")
    public void searchForPdf(){
       PDFChecker pdfChecker = new PDFChecker("directoryPath");
       String pdf =  pdfChecker.getPdfFile();
       processSendMail(pdf);
    }

    private void processSendMail(String pdf){
        if (!pdf.equals("") & this.fileNotFound){
            GlassfishLogger.log("Inside processSendMail. The fileNotFound variable is " + this.fileNotFound);
            this.fileNotFound= false;
            emailService.sendMail("dummyMail", "Dummy", "Pdf Found "+pdf);
        } 
    }
}
```

The method `processSendMail` is executed twice and somehow `this.fileNotFound` stays `true`. I receive 2 emails and then `this.fileNotFound` is set to `false`.
I've try using AtomicBoolean and also make the bean @Singleton (or @Lock(LockType.Write) as sugested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164176/how-to-make-schedule-method-to-be-called-only-once-at-a-time)). What I'm doing wrong and how to make this code to send only one mail?

**Update**

I've added a log inside the `processSendMail` method and this are the results:

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: The condition in the `if` statement in the `processSendMail(..)` method uses a single ampersand so it is performing a binary AND rather than boolean AND.  This may be your issue (or it might just be a typo if you were handtyping the code).

Comment: Thanks for the observation. In my original code I was using only a  `&`, I've change to  `&&` but the result is the same(two mails are sent).

Comment: You should compare the timestamp when the processSendMail returns with the timestamp when the next run starts

Comment: Also use Boolean and set it to null in the constructor, then use the PostConstruct to set it true

Comment: I've tried both suggestion. I've used Atomic Boolean and Boolean as suggested but same results. I've also try to use timestamps but that's a bit tricky. I am wandering why is called twice, i suppose the problem is with the schedule method

Comment: Ah ok so the problem is that the task is run twice. All the rest is noise. The boolean, the sendMail, the stateless or singleton EJB are all things unrelated to the real problem

Comment: That could provide a hint. The other thing discussed are of course  related to this problem. Thanks for help @perissf

Comment: how do you package your app? It's a single ejb jar module with this EJB?

Comment: @areus I also have classes for EmailService, PDFChecker, GlassfishLogger and a servlet but is the only EJB I have

Comment: But do you deploy an EAR? A WAR?

Comment: It'a a WAR. Do you think it have something to do with deployment?

Comment: Your code, with the obervations of @perissf, is correct. If you used a EAR, with a EJB JAR module and the same EJB inside the WAR, your EJB would be deployed twice, and would explain this behaviour. If you are only deploying a WAR I guess that's not the case

Comment: Althought, I would double-check that you haven't deployed by error an EJB JAR module in addition to the WAR

Answer (score 1):

You are doing 2 errors here, you should first read carefully a tutorial about EJB and their lifecycle.
The first error is that the `EJB` is `@Stateless`, therefore it doesn't preserve its status on each run of the scheduled task.

The second mistake is initializing the boolean default value inside the constructor. You cannot trust the constructor, because the EJB istance might be used again by the container. You must initialize it into a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`

Defining the bean as `@Singleton` will retain the status, and using the following initialization method is a good practice anyway:

```
@PostConstruct 
public void init() {

    fileNotFound = true;
}
```

See also:

[Oracle's Java EE Tutorial - Enterprise Beans](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/6nmq2cp38/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've also tried to initialize the boolean variable when is created (but i guess the state could be also lost) and as mentioned I have used @Singleton . I run using the `@PostConstruct` method as you suggest but unfortunately I still receive two mails.

Comment: Perhaps a race condition? The boolean's value is not updated until the method returns, and the following run starts before...

Comment: I've been think about this, and the only thing I've tried was to set more second to schedule method (The result is the same). I've updated the question.